# check the XML nodes are empty in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i loop through the 'roster' tag, and push in to an array, if any 'player' node is found . 
How do i check, no child elements in 'roster' tag .

I tried in the following way, but not working,

```
var strXML = '<root><club><roster/></club>\
<club><roster>
<player code="AUQ" name="AVDALOVIC, VULE" position="Guard"/>\
<player code="AQX" name="SCHULTZE, SVEN" position="Forward"/>\
</roster></club></root>';

var p = new DOMParser();
var doc = p.parseFromString(strXML, "application/xml");   
var players=doc.getElementsByTagName("player");
var i=0,arr=[];
for(i=0;i<players.length;i++){
  arr.push({
    code:players[i].getAttribute("code"),
    name:players[i].getAttribute("name"),
    position:players[i].getAttribute("position"),
  });
}
console.log(arr);
```

I am getting the output, but the output is coming blank, if any blank values are found.

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions. Could you provide, in the question, an XML example of what you mean by "no child elements in 'roster' tag?" Your question is not clear.

Comment: in the second <roster> contains <player> element but not in the first

Comment: need to push all player attributes in to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml has a problem, there should be one root element for the document

```
var strXML = '<root><club><roster/></club><club><roster><player code="AUQ" name="AVDALOVIC, VULE" position="Guard"/><player code="AQX" name="SCHULTZE, SVEN" position="Forward"/></roster></club></root>';
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7P66Z/)

Comment: @vishnu if you have the root element then the array is having two values as you can see in the fiddle

Comment: thank u, but how do i push the blank <roster> values in to an array

Comment: This is the kind of master/detail view. if u click on the table cell, it will show the details of perticular cell(details of user). so, i need to pass array to the next view. If any detail view contains blank, need to show blank page

Comment: @vishnu can you prepare a demo as i gave in the answer